# Globalize2 problems, undefined method `translates' for?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, model, globalize2

I've set up Globalize2 on a rails app however I'm getting the following error when I put translates on the model:

```
undefined method `translates' for
```

Is anyone else getting this error? It's on rails 3 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use globalize3 if you run rails3. 
You can download it from https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3 or by adding

gem "globalize3"

to you Gemfile and running bundle install.